# How do I change the value of BOOL?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, boolean, logic

How do I change the value of a BOOL in Objective-C? `lightOn` is the `BOOL` value I need help modifying.

```
@synthesize button, view;
-(IBAction)torchOn:(id)sender;
     {
          AVCaptureDevice*flashlight = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
if([flashlight isTorchAvailable] && [flashlight isTorchModeSupported:AVCaptureTorchModeOn] && [lightOn = YES])
{
    BOOL success  [[flashlight lockForConfiguration:nil]];
    if(success)
    {
        [flashlight setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOn];
        [flashlight unlockForConfiguration];
        lightOn = NO;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Learn C, then come back to ObjC. At least read a basic book on objc, and how primitives and objects are different.

Comment: `BOOL success  [[flashlight lockForConfiguration:nil]]` looks entirely inappropriate. After looking at that .. I'm not really sure *what* is/was supposed to happen (or why it would be such a difficult task).

Comment: How to change a variable? You're asking on StackOverflow how to change the value of a variable?

Comment: Your code contained few error, I corrected them. And Again I will go with @RichardJ.RossIII.

Comment: @anoop No! Don't modify broken code in a question, it makes the answers meaningless! Reverted.

Answer (score 2):

Objective-C extends the ANSI C language. Start learning there. [Here's a primer](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/A_Little_C_Primer)

```
BOOL amICrazy;

amICrazy = YES;
// amICrazy = NO;
if (amICrazy == YES)
    [self seekHelp];
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `BOOL` is not a true Boolean type, it is a typedef for `signed char`.

Comment: Of course you are right. I just didn't want to open the door too wide. I still find diving to deep to fast makes my brain seize.

Answer (score 2):

`BOOL success  [[flashlight lockForConfiguration:nil]];` is meaningless statement.

Even though I read `[[flashlight lockForConfiguration:nil]]` as `[flashlight lockForConfiguration:nil]` then `lockForConfiguration:` method should return a `BOOL` value.

And then that value can be assigned to success by this:

`BOOL success = [flashlight lockForConfiguration:nil];`